# Sending values through AJAX to PHP file to store in $_SESSION variable not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

So before I start, I've made sure to use session_start(); - which seems to have been the solution for 95% of people with this issue.

I'm creating a recipe site, and when a user clicks on an li element, the javascript code takes the id and the name of that ingredient, sends it to a php file, which should store that value in the $_SESSION variable.

All code snippets are highly summarized!

HTML:

```
<div id="ingredientContainer">
    <ul>
        <li id="ingredient-43" class="ingredient">Avocado</li>
        <li id="ingredient-90" class="ingredient">Bacon</li>
    </ul
</div>
```

JavaScript (First attempt)

```
$('#ingredientContainer .ingredient').click(function(){

    var ingredientName = $(this).html();
    var ingredientID = $(this).attr('id').split('-')


    $.ajax({
        url: "js/routes/session.php",
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            ingredientName: $(this).html(),
            ingredientID: ingredientID[1]
        }
    })

})
```

JavaScript (Second attempt)

```
 $('#ingredientContainer .ingredient').click(function(){

    var ingredientName = $(this).html();
    var ingredientID = $(this).attr('id').split('-')


    $.post("js/routes/session.php", { "ingredientName": ingredientName, "ingredientID": ingredientID[1] } );

})
```

PHP (session.php):

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if($_POST['ingredientName'] && $_POST['ingredientID']) {
        $_SESSION['finalized'][$_POST['ingredientID'])] = array(
        'ingredientID' => $_POST['ingredientID']),
        'ingredientName' => $_POST['ingredientName']
        );
    }
?>
```

After I click a few ingredients I check the $_SESSION variable but there's no values stored in it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be just how you've abbreviated your code, but it looks like there's an extra closing paranthesis in your PHP code:

```
$_SESSION['finalized'][$_POST['ingredientID'])] = array(
```

Should be

```
$_SESSION['finalized'][$_POST['ingredientID']] = array(
```

Comment: Haha, saw that as I was reviewing the submitted question. Good spotting!

Comment: That's done it. :-) Always the small things huh...just have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer as correct. Thanks again.